2011 Scion tC maintenance
Bought this car recently, and it is my first vehicle. It's on 145k miles or so, and the maintenance manual goes only to about 125k. Is there a consensus on things that may fail at that mileage or just a list of maintenance to do at x amount of miles? Finding quite varied info online.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

It's anyone's guess about high mileage part failures. Perhaps joining a Scion tC forum can help with like minded owners sharing valuable info. If you have maintenance records, that can help you determine what and where parts need attention. Can you use the maintenance interval schedule from the beginning? Long term parts replacement; spark plugs, suspension, bushings, brakes, wheel bearings, front/rear wheel alignment, etc.


Is there a consensus on things that may fail at that mileage or just a list of maintenance to do at x amount of miles?

Yes. If you look at the manual, there will likely be two things. One will be a chart of "do this at X miles." There will also likely be something in the associated text that discuss regular service items. The most basic example is oil changes: there's almost certainly an explicit mileage and time frequency of recommended oil changes (though with a vehicle of advanced age, you might want to err on the side of too often vs. too rarely). Even if you can't find the text that I'm describing, you can probably get a sense from the maintenance chart. For example, it might be obvious that fluid changes happen every 30K miles, tune ups every 60K miles, etc.
In terms of what can fail, everything will wear out eventually. My suggestion would be to watch out for aging moving and load bearing parts. On the other hand, the car probably has a lot of little rattles and squeaks that aren't really problems per se.
As a part of my preventative maintenance practice, I've always been an advocate for washing my car. It gives me a chance to really look the vehicle over, look for problem areas, drips where there shouldn't be and generally get a vibe of how she's doing.
